# Restrict file types in BlueImp JQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

Is there anyway we can restrict the file types in JQuery File Upload. From the documentation we have below code, but that is only for allowed file types. I want something for restricting file types.I want to allow all the file types but restrict .exe and .js files. Please let me know if there is any workaround for this.

```
$('#file_upload').fileUploadUIX({
    maxFileSize: 5000000, // Maximum File Size in Bytes - 5 MB
    minFileSize: 100000, // Minimum File Size in Bytes - 100 KB
    acceptFileTypes: /(zip)|(rar)$/i  // Allowed File Types
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the plugin? or the link where it is ?

Comment: This is the plugin..
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to alter the code a little more but I was able to get what you wanted by altering the regex to the following:

```
 $('#file_upload').fileUploadUIX({
        maxFileSize: 5000000, // Maximum File Size in Bytes - 5 MB
        minFileSize: 100000, // Minimum File Size in Bytes - 100 KB
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(?!exe|js)$/i  // Allowed File Types
    });
```

[image]

Comment: The above code didn't work.. Now it is not accepting any file types, whatever the extension is.

Here is the demo project in MVC where I am trying.
https://github.com/maxpavlov/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3/blob/master/jQuery-File-Upload.MVC3/Content/FileUpload/main.js

Comment: So it went from working like a charm to not working at all? What changed? Also it doesn't look like you are trying to restrict at all now, is this a new issue altogether?  Good luck.

Comment: Basically I tested your code in Regex tester it seem to work there. But when I added the same code in jQuery File Upload, it doesn't seem to like it, so thats where the problem is. Sorry I haven't tested completely when i said it worked. The link I gave is where I got that code, so i added "acceptFileTypes" attribute in my local machine. Your code is restricting all the file types.