# How can I deny only some formats in Blueimp?

Tags: php, regex, blueimp

I tried to use regex:

```
$('#uploadTable').fileupload({
    ...
    acceptFileTypes: /^[^.]+$|\.(?!(html|php)$)([^.]+$)/i,
    ...
});
```

But it not working for some reason. `.html` and `.php` files uploaded okay.

https://regex101.com/r/d2MiT6/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now none of files are foing to upload.

Comment: I have been misled by your pattern. Try [`^(?!.*\.(?:html|php)$).*`](https://regex101.com/r/J2HPtw/3)

Comment: Which file formats do you want to prohibit?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Not working too, uploading all of "1.html, 1.php, 1.png, 1.txt".

Comment: @DimaKozhevin `.html` and `.php`

Comment: @DIES Ok, if [`^(?!.*\.(?:html|php)$).*`](https://regex101.com/r/J2HPtw/3) does not work, that means there is a problem with the code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, the same result. But maybe reason that documentation only says how to restrict to specific formats but not deny it, and this feature don't supported.

Here is duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792129/restrict-file-types-in-blueimp-jquery-file-upload

Comment: @DIES Note that `/(\.|\/)(?!exe|js)$/i` regex makes no sense, as there can be no `exe` nor `js` after the end of string.

Comment: From a security point of view, it is better to accept only wanted format, than reject not wanted format.

Comment: @BenoîtZu Indeed, but if you build file storage/share service, is this a good thing? If user need to upload file with not white-listed format, and I don't know it at all?

Comment: What input goes into `acceptFileTypes`? If just the extension, then try `^(?!(html|php)$).*/i`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't know, maybe all the filename. But this not working too, blueimp says that file in queue.

Comment: @DIES ok than, there is others solutions, you could rename the file and keep the real name in your database. Also if you really want to restrict some filetype you should check the fileheaders too.